# Strange output than my expected output using LinkedList

Tags: java, arrays, loops, linked-list

When the program runs it outputs 10 random numbers and each number stores into `LinkedList` list, then this list is being displayed there are only 4-5 numbers are shown instead of 10 from the original array. Here's the simple code:

```
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Random;

public class randomSum {
    private static Random rand = new Random();
    private static LinkedList<Integer> arr = new LinkedList<Integer>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int num = 0;

        System.out.println("Original List");
        for(int i=0; i < 10; i++) {
            num = rand.nextInt(1000);
            arr.add(num);
            System.out.println(num);
        }

        System.out.println("\nLinkedList List");
        for(int j=0; j < arr.size(); j++)
            System.out.println(arr.remove(j));
    }
}
```

The output is like that, which is not exactly what I expected. They both should be the same. Why is that happening?

```
Original List
693
239
33
999
862
965
994
884
127
977

LinkedList List
693
33
862
994
127
```

Comment: `System.out.println(arr.remove(j));` Are you sure this is what you want?

Comment: Changing the List in the loop will give strange results. When looping over lists you want the data in the lists to remain the same. At least in every case I can think of...

Comment: Well I originally thought it would print each element before removing each one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to remove items while printing the [`LinkedList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html), you should use an [`Iterator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html). Removing elements like you're doing causes **undefined behavior**. Do something like that:

```
Iterator<Integer> it = arr.iterator();
while(it.hasNext()) {
    int element = it.next();
    System.out.println(element);
    it.remove();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Because on each iteration, you are removing the element you are printing. That will break up the indices. For e.g., when you remove element at `index 0`, the element at `index 1` now moves to `index 0`, but the loop index moves to `index 1` now. So the element just shifted to `index 0`, was never processed. This will happen to every alternate element, and hence you get that output.

You need to use `get(j)` instead of `remove(j)`:

```
for(int j=0; j < arr.size(); j++)
    System.out.println(arr.get(j));
```

or use [enhanced for loop](https://blogs.oracle.com/CoreJavaTechTips/entry/using_enhanced_for_loops_with):

```
for (int val: arr) {
    System.out.println(val);
}
```

Comment: @Minhaj Auto-unboxing.

Comment: @Minhaj Search for enhanced for-loop.

Answer (score 0):

In this answer I want to illustrate what actually happens, so that you understand why `remove(j)` is probably not what you want, like Rohit Jain said.

In the beginning your list looks like this:

```
693 239 33 999 862 965 994 884 127 977
```

After the first iteration, in which you call `remove(0)` it will look like this

```
239 33 999 862 965 994 884 127 977
```

so when you call `remove(1)` in you next iteration you are removing the element `33`, which was originally the third element. So each iteration you actually go forward by two elements, with respect to your original list.

Answer (score 0):

You see the regulation the output comes? It's every other number in the original list. 
every time you use arr.remove(j) , the list arr will shrink size by 1. so the loop ended while j==5, meantime arr.size()=5. And furthermore, you use arr.remove(j), then the jTH item is removed, and after j++, you skip the original (j+1)th,current jTH item. So comes to the regulation that every other number comes from the original list.

If you replace remove to get that would work as you expected.
And, you can replace remove(j) to remove(0) and change the loop ending condition to j<10, which works fine, too.